# Solving the recurrence formula $T(n) = 3T(n/2)+n^2$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

What is the solution of the following recurrence?
$$
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n^2, \quad T(1) = 0.
$$
I cannot use the master theorem since I need to know the exact final expression, not just it's big O, which I know is $O(n^2)$.

I'm stuck at the following, after 4 steps:
$$3^4T(n/2^4)+((3^6)n^2)/((2^6)2^6)+(3^3n^2)/((2^2)2^4)+(3n^2)/(2^2)+(n^2).$$

Comment: $T(n) = 0$, simple!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your recurrence is defined only when $n$ is a power of 2, so let us assume that $n = 2^m$. Expanding the recurrence, we get
\begin{align}
T(n) &= n^2 + 3T(n/2) \\ &=
n^2 + 3(n/2)^2 + 9T(n/4) \\ &=
n^2 + 3(n/2)^2 + 9(n/4)^2 + 27T(n/8) \\ &= \cdots \\ &=
n^2 + 3(n/2)^2 + 9(n/4)^2 + \cdots + 3^{m-1} (n/2^{m-1})^2 + 3^m T(n/2^m) \\ &=
n^2 + 3(n/2)^2 + 9(n/4)^2 + \cdots + 3^{m-1} (n/2^{m-1})^2 \\ &=
n^2 \left[1 + \frac{3}{4} + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m-1} \right] \\ &=
\frac{1-(3/4)^m}{1-(3/4)} n^2 \\ &=
4n^2 - 4 \cdot 3^m \\ &=
4n^2 - 4n^{\log_2 3}.
\end{align}